# How to send the incoming phone call number to another activity using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

I want to display the phone number to a textView then masking the last 4 digits if possible, but i can't run it properly, the application suddenly stops... here is a sample/reference code of what i want to do. If using toast it displays the number but when am using intent my code does not work: runtime error.

Sender(2nd Activity)

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {



            String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            Intent a = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            a.putExtra("key", incomingNumber);
            context.startActivity(a);

    }
```

main activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv1,tv2;
    String gotBread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize();
        tv1.setSelected(true);
        Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
        gotBread = gotBasket.getString("key");
        tv2.setText(gotBread);


    }

    public void initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tv1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tV1);
        tv2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tV2);
    }

}
```

here is my logcat hope it helps...

> 08-18 02:50:10.121: D/AndroidRuntime(1306): Shutting down VM 08-18
>   02:50:10.121: W/dalvikvm(1306): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0xb2a3fba8) 08-18 02:50:10.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1306): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 08-18 02:50:10.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1306): Process: com.example.detectincomingcall, PID:
>   1306 08-18 02:50:10.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.detectincomingcall/com.example.detectincomingcall.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 08-18 02:50:10.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1306):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>   08-18 02:50:10.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   08-18 02:50:10.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 08-18
>   02:50:10.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   08-18 02:50:10.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 08-18
>   02:50:10.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 08-18 02:50:10.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1306):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 08-18
>   02:50:10.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-18
>   02:50:10.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 08-18 02:50:10.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1306):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   08-18 02:50:10.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 08-18
>   02:50:10.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 08-18 02:50:10.131:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1306): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-18 02:50:10.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):   at
>   com.example.detectincomingcall.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
>   08-18 02:50:10.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 08-18
>   02:50:10.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   08-18 02:50:10.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>   08-18 02:50:10.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):   ... 11 more

Comment: what you have at MainActivity.java:21

Comment: how should i fix the error?

Comment: My friend can you please post a line at 21 of MainActivity.java ?

Comment: gotBread = gotBasket.getString("key"); here is my line 21 kind sir

Comment: your bundle gotBasket might be empty.

Comment: hmmm how would i check if it is empty using logcat sir??

Answer (score 0):

Turn the evaluation around and use [yoda notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions). This will ensure that you do not get a [NPE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) by trying to execute `null.equals()`. Also be sure to check the argument so that it is not null. Java has a strict evaluation order from left to right so you can use a [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

```
   if (null != intent && TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)))
```

And in your onCreate() you might consider being a bit paranoid

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (null != intent) {
         Bundle gotBasket = intent.getExtras();
         if (null != gotBasket) {
             gotBread = gotBasket.getString("key");
             tv2.setText(gotBread);
        }
    }
```

Comment: sir how would i check if my values are null i still don't know how to use breakpoints or logcat can you enlighten or just a reference on how to use it seems I can't understand the depth explaination

Comment: still the same error kind sir will just further study and on why it detects a null pointer, thank you for the information

Comment: thanks for the added information sir, I got it working referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330001/why-cant-i-set-textview-to-display-incoming-call-phone-number now my problem even though I followed his answer my textview is blank another new problem... but it shows in my log that the number is present...